# EC2 Instance setup with an higher volume space

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am a begineer on setting up instances on Amazon EC2. Every time I create an instance, it is always created with a 10GB harddisk space. Is there a way to create an instance with a higher volume on EC2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the size of the EBS root volume using the block device mapping options.

Depending on the AMI and Linux distro, you may need to run one of:

```
resize2fs
```

or

```
xfs_growfs
```

I wrote an article that describes how to do this with the command line tools:

> http://alestic.com/2009/12/ec2-ebs-boot-resize

This is also possible through the AWS console and API.